# Badgeicon and sound is not dispalying when notification fires in ios8 on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I'm Using LocalNotification for ios 8,Badge icon and Sound is not working fine for me even in the real device.Here is my code

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

     if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
         [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

      return YES;
}
```

in ViewController.m

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Time to get up!";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set badge before schedule notification

```
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

for sound your code is correct. check your device sound. from **settings > sounds**.

Comment: Thanks for replying and How can I Increase the badge icons for every notification,I want icon number to increase for every notification.

Comment: @user3747923 for that you have to manage it manually to save old number and increase `localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber` when fire.